# python (flask) redirect request via client

Tags: python, flask, amazon-glacier

I have been trying to do something which I think should be pretty simple.  The situation is as follows.  The client makes a request for a resource on my web server.  My flask application processes the request and determines that this resource is located at a certain location on another web server and the client should make a request of that server instead.

I know I can use the redirect function to tell the client to send a request to the remote location, but my problem is that the remote location is the Amazon Glacier servers.  These servers require a request to be made in a certain way, with a special signature (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/amazon-glacier-signing-requests.html).  My flask application knows how to go about the business of making these requests in the required way.  I essentially want to know if it's possible to send a response to my client saying, send this request (generated by my application, with all the required signing) to the Amazon server?

Any ideas?

Comment: user cant request website in amazon directly? i didnt understand how sign request

Answer (score 1):

If the request can be encoded with get params like

```
http://www.redirecturl.com/?param1=bla&param2=blub
```

then it should work no problem. Just construct the request as a string and pass it to [**redirect()**](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.redirect).

Comment: The problem is that Amazon won't return anything unless the header of the request meets certain requirements.  As far as I'm aware, you can't modify the header of a request a client makes by encoding parameters in a url.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you can't tell a client to send specific headers to a HTTP redirect URL.

Hitting the Glacier URL serverside would be the easiest. Using javascript on the clientside would only work if Glacier is implementing CORS.